# jquery dynamically edit tabs

Tags: jquery, html

I am kind of new to jquery. I am using jquery tabs and I have few buttons. What I need to do is when every button is pressed the tabs are changed dynamically. For example at loading the page the tabs are

```
<ul id="featured_tabs">
      <li><a href="#fc1" style="width: 454px">tab1/a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#fc2" style="width: 454px">tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

but when another button is pressed they become

```
<ul id="featured_tabs">
      <li><a href="#fc1" style="width: 454px">another tab1/a></li>
      <li><a href="#fc1" style="width: 454px">another tab2/a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#fc2" style="width: 454px">another tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a function to set the innerHTML of `featured_tabs` but it does not work right.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#featured_tabs').append('<li><a href="#fc3" style="width: 454px">another tab3</a></li>')
    $('#featured_tabs li').removeClass('last').last().addClass('last')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) ! The provided method should do what you want !

Answer (score 0):

Once the contents of `featured_tabs` is changed, you need to call [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh)

```
$( "#featured_tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```